# Free VPN Service without port restrictions

Tags: windows, gratis, vpn

I'm looking for a software to route the traffic of an android app running in the Bluestacks emulator through a VPN with American/British/Australian server locations. I tried installing 7 different VPN apps in Bluestacks, but they all had connection problems, indicating a compatibility issue with the emulator.

To cut the emulator out of the equation I switched to using VPNs in the host OS (Win 10). This works for routing the browser traffic but doesn't work for the app itself (Clash of Clans). The app requires port 9339 to be open which so far none of the VPNs supported.

Is there a free VPN software that doesn't restrict port access or allows for settings to accommodate my needs? The software or (PPTP service) could also be payware if it offers a free fully functional trial.

Comment: It shouldn't be the software doing the restriction. OpenVPN is the go to for VPNs and won't restrict ports. It's a matter of finding a service that allows what you want.

Comment: So does that mean that PPTP servers will never work as they only allow a single port?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a [comparison of different VPN providers](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FJTvWT5RHFSYuEoFVpAeQjuQPU4BVzbOigT0xebxTOw/edit). One that doesn't block P2P should do the trick.

Comment: Thank you for the link. That is quite an impressive list with an awesome amount of information